# Requirejs : function is not defined when i try to get it via requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I try to get some function in my html from js file that i included it via **requirejs** but it doesn't work.

Here is what i did :

**test.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       function hello()
        {
            alert('hello from function');
        }    
});
```

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            module: 'Vendor_module/js/test',
        }
    }
};
console.log('foo'); // i get well "foo" in console
```

**html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'module'], function($) {
        hello();
    });
</script>
```

Result:

```
ReferenceError: hello is not defined
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to return `hello` function in test.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){

"use strict";
      return function hello()
        {
            alert('hello from function');
        }    
});
```

and you can use that function in callback provided to require.

```
require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, hello) {
    hello();
});
```

Comment: the same error: `define(['jquery'], function($){
    "use strict";
     function hello()
    {
        alert('hello from function');
    }
    return hello();
});` , `<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, hello) {
        hello();
    });
</script>`

Comment: you just need to return hello function.

Comment: still the same problem `TypeError: hello is not a function`

Comment: I applied the same config as your requirejs link but always the same error :/

Comment: Tel me please, supposing i want to return 10 functions from my test instead one `helle function`, in the html i need to pass 10 parameters ? or there is another method to do it more pretty

Comment: if you want to return more functions I would suggest I would suggest wrapping them in an object and return that object from the module.

Comment: can you give me an exemple